# Implementing OpenNTF DOmino API in my XPages, what should I change in code?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

Regulations breakthrough! Due to major issues with recycling in XPages I got green light to install and use OpenNTF's Domino API now to leave a lot of recycling of Notes objects to ODA.

But what should I consider to change in code?

Besides creation of database object:

```
Database db = Utils.getSession().getDatabase("", "file.nsf");

Session sess = Factory.getSession(SessionType.CURRENT);
Database db = sess.getDatabase("", "file.nsf", true);
```

I noticed I saw code examples that stated SessionType.NATIVE. What is the difference?

I notice an additional parameter in sess.getDatabase("", "file.nsf", true). What is that for?

I also wonder what to do with all the exception handling that I have in my current code. Can I keep this or should I remove this?

What about logging for exceptions, do they appear automagically in openlog or not? Or how should I setup use of openlog?

Nowadays I use a different OpenNTF addon for use of OpenLog https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger . Can I remove this then?

I am looking for an example application for code but I have not found any yet. Perhaps you know a good source?

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Comment: Just a word of caution, I use it all the time, but it isn't very well documented. If you use XPiNC which I understand why most people don't, performance wise, - it becomes a black art, as you have to install it on Domino Designer which can be rather hit and miss especially at upgrade time which leads to classes not being available throughout.

Comment: We do not use XPiNC

Answer (score 1):

SessionType.NATIVE is used to run as the server. For the last few years I never used SessionAsSigner, only SessionType.NATIVE.

XPages OpenLog logger was incorporated into ODA. There may be different package names to import, but there are no differences in functionality. As I made changes to XPages OpenLog Logger, the same changes were made in ODA.

The demo app is available at http://paulswithers.me.uk/odaDemoApp and includes some documentation, including getting a database. You basically just need a single parameter and, if the database doesn’t exist, you get `null` returned, as would be normal for a Java method - no need to check if it’s

Comment: I am a bit confused. I have enabled the org.openentf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary on the Xsp Properties / Page Generation tab but when I start writing references to it with the creating a session and a database objects I get errors like 'Factory cannot be resolved', 'Session cannot be resolved to a type' , 'SessionType cannot be resolved to a variable' and 'Database cannot be resolved to a type' . Have I installed the correct plugin? –

Comment: I installed OpenNTF-Domino-API-10.0.1 since the target (Production) server is not up to v11 but the development I am working on is

Comment: In Domino Designer, you'll need the version corresponding to your version of Domino Designer. It doesn't add any code to the NSF, it uses it to verify methods are available. So v11 for DDE, v10 for the server. The only additions in v11 version are new core v11 methods. However, some plugins have been removed from Domino Designer and the server with recent releases, to streamline the products. As a result, older versions may not compile on newer DDE / server versions.

Comment: I do not know what I am doing wrong but my Notes client installation is Release 10.0.1FP4 . I downloaded from OpenNTF OpenNTF-Domino-API-10.0.1 and installed this via the provided update site. In my xsp.properties file I stated: xsp.library.depends=org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary. In my java class I wrote a simple method private void tryMe(){  
  Session sess = Factory.getSession(SessionType.CURRENT);
  Database db = sess.getDatabase("", "file.nsf", true);  
 } . Why do I get this 4 error messages? Must I import something?

Answer (score 0):

In the zipfile of the OpenNTF Domino API there is an apidoc folder this contains javadoc for the api.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I have enabled the org.openentf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary on the Xsp Properties / Page Generation tab but when I start writing references to it with the creating a session and a database objects I get errors like 'Factory cannot be resolved', 'Session cannot be resolved to a type' , 'SessionType cannot be resolved to a variable'  and 'Database cannot be resolved to a type' . Have I installed the correct plugin?